# Is there any way to bind data to data.frame by some index?

Tags: r

```
#For say, I got a situation like this
user_id = c(1:5,1:5)
time = c(1:10)
visit_log = data.frame(user_id, time)

#And I've wrote a method to calculate interval
interval <- function(data) {
    interval = c(Inf)
    for (i in seq(1, length(data$time))) {
        intv = data$time[i]-data$time[i-1]
        interval = append(interval, intv)
    }

    data$interval = interval
    return (data)
}

#But when I want to get intervals by user_id and bind them to the data.frame,
#I can't find a proper way
#Is there any method to get something like
new_data = merge(by(visit_log, INDICE=visit_log$user_id, FUN=interval))

#And the result should be
    user_id time interval
1        1    1      Inf
2        2    2      Inf
3        3    3      Inf
4        4    4      Inf
5        5    5      Inf
6        1    6        5
7        2    7        5
8        3    8        5
9        4    9        5
10       5   10        5
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: user_id=c(1:5,1:5), time=c(1:10)

Comment: Your `interval()` function isn't very efficient, you should **never** expand/concatenate in a loop like that as R has to copy and enlarge the object every iteration of the loop. You also need to think in a vectorised manner to get the best out of R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can replace your loop with the `diff()` function which computes the differences between adjacent indices in a vector, for example:

```
> diff(c(1,3,6,10))
[1] 2 3 4
```

To that we can prepend `Inf` to the differences via `c(Inf, diff(x))`.

The next thing we need is to apply the above to each `user_id` individually. For that there are many options, but here I use `aggregate()`. Confusingly, this function returns a data frame with a `time` component that is itself a matrix. We need to convert that matrix to a vector, relying upon the fact that in R, columns of matrices are filled first. Finally, we add and `interval` column to the input data as per your original version of the function.

```
interval <- function(x) {
    diffs <- aggregate(time ~ user_id, data = x, function(y) c(Inf, diff(y)))
    diffs <- as.numeric(diffs$time)
    x <- within(x, interval <- diffs)
    x
}
```

Here is a slightly expanded example, with 3 time points per user, to illustrate the above function:

```
> visit_log = data.frame(user_id = rep(1:5, 3), time  = 1:15)
> interval(visit_log)
   user_id time interval
1        1    1      Inf
2        2    2      Inf
3        3    3      Inf
4        4    4      Inf
5        5    5      Inf
6        1    6        5
7        2    7        5
8        3    8        5
9        4    9        5
10       5   10        5
11       1   11        5
12       2   12        5
13       3   13        5
14       4   14        5
15       5   15        5
```

Comment: And may I add a question here. Is there any difference between you using within() and direct assignment x$interval <- diffs?

Comment: @iano Yes, `within()` is slower than direct assignment, other than that, No. I tend to prefer it (`with() or `within()`) as it makes the code cleaner and the intention of the code clearer than scattering `$`s everywhere, but here it is probably overkill and `x$interval <- diffs` would be fine.