# How to get the index of data block in a data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame like this:

```
    a b
1   1 2
2   1 3
3   2 3
4   2 5
```

It's sorted by `a` and I need the indices of different `a`'s. Now I'm using for loop, however it's not elegant.

Comment: what is the output you are looking for in this example ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5140222/is-there-any-way-to-bind-data-to-data-frame-by-some-index?rq=1

Comment: Does duplicated work, i.e., which(!duplicated(x$a))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
# this will give you the row indices
lapply(unique(dat$a), function(a) which(dat$a==a))
```

If you want your results to be named, use:

```
U <- unique(dat$a)
names(U) <- U
lapply(U, function(a) which(dat$a==a))

# Produces: 
#  $`1`
#  [1] 1 2
#
#  $`2`
#  [1] 3 4
```